# Parse - Push notification not working in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, parse-platform, ios8

I am registering push with Parse with following code:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                       categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else
#endif
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                                           UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                                           UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

In iOS 7 it's working properly, but when I am sending push from iOS 8 it's not working and returns this error:

> `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later parse.`

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: yes Thanks @admdrew. this was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the error and [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/enabledRemoteNotificationTypes), `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` is deprecated for iOS 8:

> Use the [`isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications) method instead.